# perform a distinct operation on a projection in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Similar to but distinct from other SO questions:

**UPDATED**

I have a collection, the records all have a field `date` which is an `ISODate`, for example:

```
{
  date: 12 January 2020,
  event: "start",
},
{
  date: 23 January 2020,
  event: "stop"
},
{
  date: 23 January 2020,
  event: "stop",
},
{
  date: 2 March 2020,
  event: "pause"
}
```

I want to find (for example) the distinct days in January of 2020 where an event of any kind occurred -- so, 12 and 23.

More generally, I want to find all the distinct days (ie integers) between two dates. I know I can do:

```
db.collection('test').distinct('date', {
     date: {
       $gte: new Date(start),
       $lte: new Date(end),
     },
  });
```

But this does **not** give me the day, it gives me the whole date. On the other hand, it's easy to get a non-distinct list of all days between two dates using using `$dayOfMonth` with projection.

Please help!

Comment: What's your question? It's confusing

Comment: updated! hope it's clear now....

Comment: ok, do you really have date in this format? Or it's jus a sample

Comment: no, it's an ordinary ISOdate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oZjEMHiHoEt)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "key": {
        $gte: ISODate("2020-01-01"),
        $lte: ISODate("2020-01-31")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$key"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "day": {
        $dayOfMonth: "$_id"
      },
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

It uses `group` to get unique values.